# Java functional interface and wildcard

Tags: java

I have a functional interface defined as

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SetupConstraint<T extends GraphicalObject> {
    public void setup(T object);
}
```

The class hierarchy here is

```
OutlineRect is a subclass of GraphicalObject
SelectableOutlineRect is a subclass of OutlineRect that implements Selectable
```

Now I have

```java
SelectableOutlineRect r = new SelectableOutlineRect();
SetupConstraint<? extends OutlineRect> constraint = ...; // from somewhere else
constraint.setup(r);
```

In the final line of code, the compiler gives the following error:

```
The method setup(capture#1-of ? extends OutlineRect) in the type
SetupConstraint<capture#1-of ? extends OutlineRect> is not
applicable for the arguments (SelectableOutlineRect)Java(67108979)
```

I'm so confused about this right now... I'm fairly new to this but I believe since SelectableOutlineRect is a subclass of OutlineRect this should not report an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: In my experience, `?` wildcards only work in method declarations.

Comment: Your `SetupConstraint` interface is a consumer, so at _use sites_ you should have `? super ...` instead of `? extends ...`. Related: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/6395627).

Comment: @Powerlord They can also be used in the parameterized type of a field/variable.

Comment: @Slaw Oh wow thank you for the link. It works when I changed the code to SetupConstraint<? super SelectableOutlineRect>. But may I ask how should I interpret SetupConstraint being a consumer? It's kinda different from Collection or others which are easier to understand.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) are two links that explain the stuff pretty well. Keep in mind, that ```?``` creates a *dynamic* type for you at runtime.

Comment: Your interface is a consumer because the type variable (`T`) is only used as a parameter type. The method(s) _consume_ arguments of type `T`. The interface would be a producer if the type variable was only used as a return type. In this case, the method(s) _produce_ results of type `T`. Neither case precludes the existence of interfaces that have some consumer methods _and_ some producer methods, or even some methods that are both.